# Adding hours to calculated field in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I currently have this formula in a calculated field in SharePoint.

=IF(TEXT(Created,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")="12/30/1899","",(TEXT(Created,"mm/dd/yyyy")))

This returns the Created Date in Text form.. but since our SP server is on the west coast. There is a 3 hour lag in time.

How would I add 3 hours to this formula?

Answer (score 1):

Since adding Specific numbers is whole days, `[Created] + 1` would be Adding 1 day, you can cut the value in to 24 parts and add specific hours.

`[Created] + (3/24)` for 3 hours

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Created+(1/24/60*180)
```

[referenced thread](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-add-and-subtract-hours-and-minutes-from-date-and-time-fields-in-sharepoint-lists/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this is solved the date compare with current date for Birthday list in SharePoint (IST):

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),Month,Day)+(1/24/60*810)
```